# Warning: modules_install: missing 'System.map' file. Skipping depmod

Tags: linux, modules, buildroot, makefile

I am trying to insert a kernel module using `depmod` and `modprobe` utilities in-order to resolve any dependencies. When I build the module it throws "**Warning: modules_install: missing 'System.map' file. Skipping depmod**."

And later when I try to execute `modprobe` it throws an error saying "**modprobe: FATAL: Module i2c_eeprom_client.ko not found in directory /lib/modules/4.19.58-v7+**"

Below is the make file I am using:

```
obj-m += i2c_eeprom_client.o
KDIR = /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build

all:
    make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) modules
    make -C $(KDIR) M=$(PWD) modules_install

clean:
    make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) clean
```

And below is the output of build:

```
make -C /lib/modules/4.19.58-v7+/build M=/home/pi/work/eeprom modules
make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.19.58-v7+'
  Building modules, stage 2.   
  MODPOST 1 modules
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.19.58-v7+'
make -C /lib/modules/4.19.58-v7+/build M=/home/pi/work/eeprom 
modules_install  
make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.19.58-v7+'
  INSTALL /home/pi/work/eeprom/i2c_eeprom_client.ko
  DEPMOD  4.19.58-v7+
Warning: modules_install: missing 'System.map' file. Skipping depmod.
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.19.58-v7+'
```

How can i fix this problem ? Please help

Platform : Raspberry PI 3b+, Raspbian - linux 4.19.58-v7+

Comment: this same question seems to have answers here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/57521081/